# 20.04.2 + Ryzen 4k 60fps video playback

Tags: 20.04, kernel, vlc, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

Have a laptop with the following specs, and I can't get 4k videos to play smoothly. All I see if 1 frame every few seconds.

- Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS
- Kernel 5.11.0-27-generic
- Ryzen 7 pro 4750u with radeon graphics
- 16GB RAM

Tried VLC 3.0.16(latest stable) and the default player, and the results are still the same.